# How does the current drawn from a battery change when it is stepped down using a regulator?

Tags: current, step-down

I'm wondering what happens to the current when the voltage is stepped down using a regulator. here is the situation: I have a load which draws about 500mA at 3.3 volts, and I would like to regulate power received from a 9 volt battery to the specified 3.3 volts. If the 9 volt battery has 500mAh, will it last for more than an hour?

Comment: That would depend on which kind of regulator you will use. Will it be a linear regulator or a switch mode regulator?

Comment: which one would convert the excess voltage to current? i normally use linear regulators. @Justme

Comment: Linear regulators do not convert excess voltage to current.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a linear regulator, 500 mA out of the regulator means 500 mA goes in to the regulator, plus slightly more to power the regulator itself.

If a 9V battery has 500 mAh capacity, it most likely is not rated 500 mAh at 500 mA current, so it won't last even an hour.

With a switch mode regulator, 3.3V at 500mA will take only less than 200 mA at 9V, so it's possible that a battery 500 mAh capacity might just power the load for slightly over an hour.

Answer (score -1):

Energy unit conversion: 1 Watt-hour equals 3600 joules.

Energy stored in 0.500 Ah 9 volt battery is 4.5 Watt-hour x 3600 joules per Watt-hour equals 16,200 {J}.

Watt {W} is also joule per second {J/s}.

If the load draws 1.65 {J/s} then divide 16,200 {J} by 1.65 {J/s} which is 9,818 seconds {s}. Divide by 3600 to get hours gives 2.72 hour {hr}. So the battery in theory has enough energy to power the load for 2.72 hour.

Power dissipation in a linear regulator is 5.7 volts (9 - 3.3) times 0.5 amps equals 2.85 joule per second. This means the load and regulator would draw 1.65 + 2.85 = 4.5 joule per second. Divide 16,200 by 4.5 gives 3600 which is 1 hour. However at 0.5 amp draw the 9 volt battery will develop internal heat due to internal resistance. This power loss has not been factored into the above calculations and would further reduce the amount of time the battery could effectively power the load.